# MidiSystem.getSequencer() giving error at compile time - symbol not found

Tags: java

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;


public class MiniMiniMusicApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MiniMiniMusicApp mini = new MiniMiniMusicApp();
        mini.play();
    }//close main

    public void play()
    {
        try
        {
            Sequencer player = new MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            player.open();

            Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);

            Track track = seq.createTrack();

            ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
            a.setMessage(144, 1, 44, 100);
            MidiEvent noteOn = new MidiEvent(a,1);
            track.add(noteOn);

            ShortMessage b = new ShortMessage();
            b.setMessage(128, 1, 44, 100);
            MidiEvent noteOff = new MidiEvent(b, 16);
            track.add(noteOff);

            player.setSequence(seq);

            player.start();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//close play
}//close class
```

I have version 1.8.  When I try to compile this I get the 'cannot find symbol' error from the MidiSystem.getSequencer() line.  I know it's there because I just checked the online API and I have the latest version.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: The thing after `new` has to be a class. `MidiSystem.getSequencer` is not a class.

Comment: and now it compiles.  I knew it was something small I was overlooking.  Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sequencer player = new MidiSystem.getSequencer();
```

from the above line remove `new` keyword,
It is used to create a new Object from a class. And I believe `MidiSystem.getSequencer()` returns a `Sequecer` object

so it should be

```
Sequencer player = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
```

Comment: this did it.  I'll mark it as answer asap